# Limit output depth of jq

Tags: json, jq

I want to explore arbitrary document using `jq`. To that end, I would like to limit the depth to which `jq` descends into documents and only show me the first `n`, e.g. 3, levels.

Suppose I have the following JSON document:

```
{
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": {
                "d": {
                    "e": "foo"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "f": {
        "g": {
            "h": {
                "i": {
                    "j": "bar"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "k": {
        "l": {
            "m": {
                "n": {
                    "o": "baz"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect the result

```
{
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": {}
        }
    },
    "f": {
        "g": {
            "h": {}
        }
    },
    "k": {
        "l": {
            "m": {}
        }
    }
}
```

This is a fairly simple task if I know the document's structure in advance, but frequently, I don't. That is why I want to be able to have `jq` show only the first n levels of the document structure, which may be an arbitrary nesting of dictionaries and arrays.

A more complex example could be:

```
[
    { "a": { "b": { "c": { "d": { "e": "foo"}}}}},
    { "f": [ { "g": "foo"}]},
    [ "h", "i", "j" ]
]
```

where I would expect the result

```
[
    { "a": { "b": {}},
    { "f": [{}]},
    [ "h", "i", "j" ]
]
```

Can I make `jq` do this?

Comment: This is useful - https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/306. Not an issue page actually, explains the problem well

Comment: Another related discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33627427/320399

Comment: IMO this would probably be possible with about 4-10 lines of recursive python code. i have not written that code yet tho.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Combining the `del` function with the `.[]?` array/object value iterator to delete any key/value nested at the fourth level seems to give the result you are looking for:

```json
$ jq 'del(.[]?[]?[]?[]?)' <<'EOT'
[
    { "a": { "b": { "c": { "d": { "e": "foo"}}}}},
    { "f": [ { "g": "foo"}]},
    [ "h", "i", "j" ]
]
EOT
[
  {
    "a": {
      "b": {}
    }
  },
  {
    "f": [
      {}
    ]
  },
  [
    "h",
    "i",
    "j"
  ]
]
```

The `.[]?` version of the `.[]` iterator filter is needed to prevent `jq` from complaining when it tries to iterate over an item that is not an array or object.

To be honest, I couldn't find any direct mention of the array/object iterator filter in the form shown above (basically: `.[][]`) anywhere in the documentation. A less concise but clearly documented version would be:

```
$ jq 'del(.[]? | .[]? | .[]? | .[]?)' ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `path(..)` you can generate all possible path expressions for the given document.  You may then select the ones that are too long with e.g. `select(length > 3)`.  These may be deleted with `delpaths()`.

This has the benefit of allowing us to write a neat looking expression which is easily parametrized with a single integer (which could be passed into `jq` with `--argjson`), but the `path(..)` expression is at the same time needlessly "heavy" (produces *every single* path in the document).

```bash
$ jq 'delpaths([path(..) | select(length > 3)])' file
{
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "c": {}
    }
  },
  "f": {
    "g": {
      "h": {}
    }
  },
  "k": {
    "l": {
      "m": {}
    }
  }
}
```

---

Testing with the example document from the end of the question:

```bash
$ jq . file
[
  {
    "a": {
      "b": {
        "c": {
          "d": {
            "e": "foo"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "f": [
      {
        "g": "foo"
      }
    ]
  },
  [
    "h",
    "i",
    "j"
  ]
]
```

```bash
$ jq --argjson d 1 'delpaths([path(..) | select(length > $d)])' file
[
  {},
  {},
  []
]
```

```bash
$ jq --argjson d 2 'delpaths([path(..) | select(length > $d)])' file
[
  {
    "a": {}
  },
  {
    "f": []
  },
  [
    "h",
    "i",
    "j"
  ]
]
```

```bash
$ jq --argjson d 3 'delpaths([path(..) | select(length > $d)])' file
[
  {
    "a": {
      "b": {}
    }
  },
  {
    "f": [
      {}
    ]
  },
  [
    "h",
    "i",
    "j"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This method may not be ideal because it relies on whitespace which could change between versions of jq, but it is a powerful method in the sense that it could be applied to similar situations with other tools.

After jq does a pretty print, it will prepend whitespace to elements which are further down the json tree. So, if you just do an inverted grep for lines with a certain number of leading spaces, you can remove any elements which are beyond a certain depth. In the example below I've removed elements with a depth equal to or greater than 4 similar to your example.

```
grifball@grifball-Computer:~$ cat limit-output.json
{"a":{"b":{"c":{"d":{"e":"foo"}}}},"f":{"g":{"h":{"i":{"j":"bar"}}}},"k":{"l":{"m":{"n":{"o":"baz"}}}}}
grifball@grifball-Computer:~$ cat limit-output.json | jq
{
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "c": {
        "d": {
          "e": "foo"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "f": {
    "g": {
      "h": {
        "i": {
          "j": "bar"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "k": {
    "l": {
      "m": {
        "n": {
          "o": "baz"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
grifball@grifball-Computer:~$ cat limit-output.json | jq | grep -v '^\s\{8\}'
{
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "c": {
      }
    }
  },
  "f": {
    "g": {
      "h": {
      }
    }
  },
  "k": {
    "l": {
      "m": {
      }
    }
  }
}
```